# Kivy Layout embedding

Tags: python, kivy

When embedding a layout later it works, but when embedding a layout first it does not work. In design file when mylayout2 is embedded 1st and then the code in mylayout, only element of mylayout is visible. when mylayout2 is embedded later then only elements from mylayout and mylayout2 are visible. Please help, unable to understand what difference it brings.

main file:

```py
from kivy.app import App

class MyLabApp(App):
    pass

MyLabApp().run()
```

Design file:

```
mylayout:
<mylayout@BoxLayout>:
    mylayout2:
    Button:
        text:"B1"

<mylayout2@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        text:"B2"
```

Comment: read ---> [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Change all the class names (or atleast the class `mylayout2`) to Upper case (Atleast like `Mylayout2`).

Comment: Thanks for improving the writing/formatting but the question remain same.

Comment: Did you try changing name(s) as suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

Was not aware that kivy does care about class name notation. Changing the class name as per nomenclature has worked and resolved the issue.
This code does work.

```
MyLayoutOne:
<MyLayoutOne@BoxLayout>:
    MyLayoutTwo:
    Button:
        text:"B1"

<MyLayoutTwo@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        text:"B2"
```